# GitFlow: How do I know which feature I am working on?

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm new to Git Flow. My manager started a new feature on my behalf (on my machine) just before he left for holiday. I now have to "finish" this feature but I have no idea what the feature was called. How can I find out it's name or how can I submit this feature?

I have a list of the commands and order written down but I just need the name of the feature or does it actually not matter what I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feature is just a usual git branch. You can check which branch you're on by using:

```
$ git branch
develop
feature/load-test
* feature/push
master
```

The branch (or feature) you're on is marked with `*`.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with git flow,

You simply need to print out the the branches your HEAD currently points to:

```
git branch
```

The current one will be marked with *.

---

#### Branches color:

You can set the colors of the branch output for your needs

```
[color]
  ui = auto
[color "branch"]
  current = yellow bold reverse
  local = green
  remote = red
```

Add this to your config and you will have branches with colors.

[image]